# What is the correct location for node.js packages

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've noticed that packages are installing themselves into two different places and I wondered which one is correct, or maybe it doesn't matter. The two locations are;

```
C:\nodejs\lib\node_modules
C:\nodejs\node_modules
```

Now I can hear the sighs as you realise I'm running node on windows but it works fine. Kind of:)

Anyway, when I run `npm ls` it only lists packages in `C:\nodejs\node_modules` which makes me think that's the correct location. But then noticed that the npm itself is in `C:\nodejs\lib\node_modules` which makes me think that's the correct location. Is there a correct location? They all seem to work fine. I've moved modules from `C:\nodejs\node_modules` to `C:\nodejs\lib\node_modules` and they still work OK.

Your answers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages go here

`Drive:\path\to\your\code\node_modules`

I happen to Store my code in `H:\dos\pd` so my node_modules goes in `H:\dos\pd\node_modules`

That's just my `pd` modules of course. If I'm working on some other code it goes in `Drive:\some\sensible\location\node_modules`

Comment: so if you're using NPM you say `npm install xx` inside your project folder? i did this in the parent folder so i had to install every plugin once for every project to use it ...

Comment: @pkyeck nope. Your supposed to generate a package.json file and call `npm link`

Comment: @pkyeck as an aside I havnt tried npm on windows so I may be recommending something thats completely broken on windows but works on linux

Comment: i'm also using osx or ubuntu - so no problem there :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I can put modules anywhere then. Cool. I need to spend a lot more time with node.

Answer (score 0):

There are different locations in which modules are searched for.

The [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders) about modules describes in detail how node searches for modules. Normally there's a system-wide location for modules (often `/lib/node_modules/`), but every project can maintain its modules folder with the exact versions it needs. Those override the global modules.

There's not really a right and wrong. It just can get messy if there are node_modules folders everywhere.